# Retrieving collection from linked eloquent models laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using laravel 5.3 and need a bit of help with Eloquent model queries. I have three models (UserDetails, Categories, Articles). I have a relationship between UserDetails->Categories (belongstoMany), and a relationship between Categories->Articles (belongstoMany) which work well. However how would I go about getting the relationship data between Userdetails->Categories->Articles.

Each individual relationship is working fine i.e. Userdetails::find(1)->categories and Categories::find(1)->Articles.

I have a feeling that scopes may be the answer but they don't seem to work when I've attempted it.

**Relationships in models**

UserDetails.php

```
 public function Categories(){
    return $this->belongstoMany('App\Categories', 'users_cats',  'user_id','cat_id');
}
```

Categories.php

```
  public function articles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article', 'article_categories', 'categoryID', 'articleID');
}
```

Ive looked into HasManyThrough function but again, I'm having issues implementing it, as far as I can see it should be

```
  return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Article', 'App\Categories', TertiaryForeignKey, FinalForeignKey, LocalForeignKey);
```

My tables are set up as

**articles_categories pivot table**

articleID – primary key of the article

categoryID – primary key of the category

**users_cats pivot table**

user_id – primary key of the userdetails

cat_id – primary key of the categories

Based on this it the hasManyThrough should look like this?

```
 public function articles(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Article', 'App\Categories', 'user_id', 'articleID', 'id');
}
```

however this returns the error
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.user_id' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

#### update

So if you want to have this kind of relationship

userdetails->categories->articles

then you need to make this:

Userdetail model:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
}

public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Article::class, Categories::class);
}
```

Category model:

```
public function userdetails()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Userdetails::class);
}

public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
}
```

Article model:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

Then you can call `UserDetails::find(1)->articles->get();` directly

Comment: I am using a custom able structure for my relationship data, and that returns  the error 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.user_details_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `journalarticle`.*, `categories`.`user_details_id` from `journalarticle` inner join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `journalarticle`.`categories_id` where `categories`.`user_details_id` = 1)

Do I need to pass my keys to the HasManyThrough function? Ive added my table structure to the original post

Comment: you should always name your columns by following the convention, that is categorie_id, article_id, user_id when creating foreign keys....and then you don't need to specify those keys when you are creating relationships, just name the class and that's it. It is much simpler and it should be done that way!

Comment: I fixed the tables but still it's returning that error. Is the issue of running a hasThrough many with two many to many relationships?

Comment: Oh yes...you need to make the other relationships as well...i will update my answer

Comment: i would recommend to change the model name from Category to Tag because the laravel works automatically with naming the table by adding "s" to the end of the Model name....

Comment: The model is called categories, I have set up my own pivot tables with the ManytoMany relationship.

The solution you proposed isn't working but I think its because I have created the pivot tables. I'm starting to pull my hair out over this one.

I feel there is something obvious that I'm not getting about eloquent relationships in laravel. Can you have a manytomany relationship without the pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare the relationship like this in the 
UserDetails.php model:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Categories::class);
}
```

in Categories.php model:

```
 public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Articles::class);
}
```

Then you can retrieve the collection of categories in your controller:

```
$userdetails = UserDetails::get();
```

pass that $categories variable into your View and display each record with an foreach loop (where the articles is the function in your model)

```
   @foreach($userdetails->categories as $usercategories )
        <div> {{$usercategories->name}} </div>

        @foreach($usercategories->articles as $categoryarticles )
          <div> {{$categoryarticles->name}} </div>
        @endforeach
   @endforeach
```

with the second foreach you will access the articles of the categories that belongs to the user.

Comment: Yes I can get the Articles associated with a category fine, as per the original question I want to get all the articles associated with a category which the user has so UserDetails->Categories->Articles, not Categories->Articles.

Comment: I have edited my answer i hope it helps you @user5067291